# Typedef in template is causing shadows template parm error

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

I have template class in which I am using typedef to declare a map as follows:

```
#include <map>

template <typename T> class LocalStub {
  typedef std::map<T, T> QueryMap;
  typedef std::pair<T, T> QueryPair;
  typedef QueryMap::iterator QueryMapIterator;

public:
  LocalStub();
  ~LocalStub();
  void AddQuery(const T &, const T &);
  const T &Answer(const T &) const;
private:
  QueryMap _queryMap;
};
```

---

## Compilation errors

```
../src/LocalStub/include/localstub.hpp:12: error: declaration of 'class T'
../src/LocalStub/include/localstub.hpp:11: error:  shadows template parm 'class T'
../src/LocalStub/include/localstub.hpp:13: error: template declaration of 'typedef'
../src/LocalStub/include/localstub.hpp:14: error: declaration of 'class T'
../src/LocalStub/include/localstub.hpp:11: error:  shadows template parm 'class T'
../src/LocalStub/include/localstub.hpp:15: error: template declaration of 'typedef'
../src/LocalStub/include/localstub.hpp:16: error: declaration of 'class T'
../src/LocalStub/include/localstub.hpp:11: error:  shadows template parm 'class T'
../src/LocalStub/include/localstub.hpp:17: error: template declaration of 'typedef'
../src/LocalStub/include/localstub.hpp:26: error: 'QueryMap' does not name a type
```

---

What am I doing wrong? I don't understand why I am getting that error.

Comment: => `typedef typename QueryMap::iterator QueryMapIterator;`

Comment: @AMA excuse my question but why should I add typename>

Comment: You should look at [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to write the keyword `typename` with `QueryMapIterator`. Here is the updated version:

```
template <typename T> class LocalStub {
  typedef std::map<T, T> QueryMap;
  typedef std::pair<T, T> QueryPair;
  typedef typename QueryMap::iterator QueryMapIterator;

public:
  LocalStub();
  ~LocalStub();
  void AddQuery(const T &, const T &);
  const T &Answer(const T &) const;
private:
  QueryMap _queryMap;
};
```

The reason for this requirement is that the compiler doesn't at this point know whether `QueryMapIterator` describes a member variable or a nested type

Comment: thank you for your answer Consistent . Why should I add the typename in that case?

Comment: I have updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR - `typedef typename QueryMap::iterator QueryMapIterator;`

Longer version:
`QueryMap::iterator` is a [dependant name](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name) and thus it is required that You use `typename` before `typedef`ing it. Dependant name problem comes from fact that inside the template construction `type::something` the `something` may refer either to type, value or function as in below example:

```
template<class T>
struct foo{
    void bar(){ T::something; }
};

struct baz{
    using something = int;
};

struct bez{
    static const int something = 0;
};
```

Thus the `typename` is needed to give additional information to the compiler if the name You are passing refers to a type.